# How do you wait on multiple XHR in Cypress that match the same intercept

Tags: cypress

In my app after login in from a clean state, there are a series of sync queries that are being fired to make sure that the local data is updated. There is a loading screen while this is happening. I just need to cypress to wait for all these calls to finish before performing the test.

`cy.intercept()` is identifying the call, but `cy.wait()` only waits for the first one to be finished.

Is there a way to create the alias dynamilcally or have the application wait for the spinner to disapper?

[image]

```
describe('Navigation', function () {
beforeEach(function () {
    // Programmatically login via Amazon Cognito API
    cy.intercept('POST', '**/graphql').as('dataStore');
    cy.loginByCognitoApi(Cypress.env('cognito_username'), Cypress.env('cognito_password'));
    cy.wait(['@dataStore']);
});

it('shows logged in', function () {
    cy.get('[data-test=logo]').should('be.visible');
});
```

Comment: What you can do is add and assertion that needs to be satisfied before you intercept. Here are some examples https://dev.to/lockn/how-to-wait-for-requests-on-cypress-tests-9fj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can repeat wait on a single intercept, so count up the number of orange `dataStore` tags (looks like 11) and wait that amount of times

```js
cy.intercept('POST', '**/graphql').as('dataStore');
cy.loginByCognitoApi(Cypress.env('cognito_username'), Cypress.env('cognito_password'));
Cypress._.times(11, () => {
  cy.wait('@dataStore')
})
```

Or it might be 10 - looking at the route defn. In any case, experiment. The app should be consistent in the calls it makes.

Comment: interesting solution. In my particular case, it's not always the same amount of calls. I did come across this open issue in cypress GitHub https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/17819

Comment: Does `(new url) http://localhost/snashots` at the end of the log mark the end of XHR calls?

Comment: `http://localhost/snapshots` marks a redirect after loading has completed and I ended up waiting for that redirect. It's 90% effective, but if there happens to be a slow connection the test fails.     
`cy.url({ timeout: 20000 }).should('contain', '/snapshots');`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar case. What I do is store an array of objects in a different file and each object represents a specific test scenario. That way you can iterate through your test cases an assign an alias dynamically.

So you could do something like this:

```
beforeEach(function () {
   yourArray.forEach((testcase) => {
    cy.intercept('POST', '**/graphql').as(`${testcase.testname}datastore`);
    cy.loginByCognitoApi(Cypress.env('cognito_username'), 
    Cypress.env('cognito_password'));
    cy.wait(`@${testcase.testname}datastore`);
}
    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of requests aren't consistent, something I've done is the following (I've since put this in a command to use in multiple places):

```
cy.intercept('POST', '**/graphql').as('dataStore');
cy.loginByCognitoApi(Cypress.env('cognito_username'),Cypress.env('cognito_password'));
cy.get('@dataStore.all').then(xhrs => cy.wait(Array(xhrs.length).fill('@dataStore')));
```

Doing a wait on the alias with "all" returns all of the calls made to aliased route that Cypress has seen since the alias was made.

Comment: Note - the call to `cy.get('@dataStore.all')` can occur before all requests complete.

Answer (score 0):

@user16695029 is a great solution.

If you run into the issue of API calls not being predictable (kicked off by a timer async etc), then keeping track of API call count might be useful:

at the start of your test code

```
let responseCounter = 0;
cy.intercept({ method: 'POST', url: '/save', middleware: true }, req => {
    req.on('response', (res) => {
        responseCounter++;
    })
}).as('save')
```

then later

```
let expectedSaveCount = 12;
Cypress._.times(expectedSaveCount - responseCounter, () => {
    cy.wait('@save')
})
cy.get('@save.all').should('have.length', expectedSaveCount)
```

Comment: Actually `cy.get('@save.all').should('have.length', expectedSaveCount)` is redundant. And `expectedSaveCount - responseCounter` is `12 - 0`.